# $PYTHONHOME is pointing to non existent Python version on my Mac

Tags: python, macos, path, environment-variables

When I echo out my `PYTHONHOME` variable on my Mac I get the following

```
$ echo $PYTHONHOME
$ /usr/local/lib/python3.3/:/usr/local/lib/python3.3/lib/:/usr/local/lib/python3.3/lib/site-packages/
```

However, when I actually browse to `/usr/local/lib/` in the Finder, there is no `python3.3` directory. There are `python2.7` and `python3.4`, but no `python3.3`

Is there something wrong? What is the problem?

Note that I have not set `PYTHONHOME` in `.bashrc` nor in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Did you ever have version 3.3 installed?

Comment: I don't really have an answer, but I suppose when you updated to 3.4, it didn't update the environment variable for some reason...

Comment: where are they set? I cannot find them

Comment: I suppose the installation script sets them. But you could just manually set it to 3.4.

Comment: Bin files  is not inside /lib file dirs. You check library not binary !